# In Django's ORM, is there a way to detect whether code is executing inside a transaction?

Tags: django, psycopg2, django-orm

Eg, I want this function:

```py
from django.db import transaction


with transaction.atomic():
    assert inside_transaction() == True


assert inside_transaction() == False
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is it possible to detect directly in psycopg2 if not in Django's ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/402ae37873974afa5093e6d6149175a118979cd9/django/db/transaction.py#L135) for the `Atomic` class that is used by `transaction.atomic` it sets a flag `in_atomic_block` on the connection. Hence if you want to check if your code is inside a transaction you can write the follows:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    assert transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block == True

assert transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block == False
```

**Note**: The `get_connection` function optionally takes a parameter `using`, in case you specify `using` for the call to `transaction.atomic`, you should pass it to `get_connection` as well.

Better yet since `get_connection` is a private API just write a small function of your own to check this:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.db import (
    DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, connections,
)


def inside_transaction(using=None):
    if using is None:
        using = DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
    return connections[using].in_atomic_block


with transaction.atomic():
    assert inside_transaction() == True


assert inside_transaction() == False
```